# Удержание постоянного соединения

Tags: веб-программирование, сокет, highload

Рационально ли держать постоянное соединение сервера с клиентом, если клиент посылает информацию с промежутком в 5 - 10 минут?

Comment: смотря чем держать, сам по себе сокет ест очень мало. (посмотрите на im сервера для примера в некоторых случаях сотни тысяч и даже миллионы постоянных соединений)

Answer (score 1):

Если реакция на посылку нужна быстрая, а на сервере реализована эффективная схема мультиплексирования сокетов, то вполне рационально.

Если время реакции на запрос не критично, то можно и рвать соединение.

Фактически, при такой интенсивности - не имеет значения.

Какие минусы: если DoS, у вас могут быстро скушать все доступные процессу дескрипторы и, если будут держать, может так статься,  что новые клиенты подключиться не смогут. В случае закрытия соединения по завершению обмена - нужно более интенсивно DoS проводить. Но противодействие атакам - тема отдельного обсуждения.